# Any possible way to identify calling phone number in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I am building an app that sits in a background and displays extra information pulled from an API when a normal phone call is received. I also have the list of phone numbers which are to be "identified" beforehand.

Now I am aware there is no way to directly get the calling phone number, but is there really not any other way around that even with the list of numbers on the latest ?

I know about CallKit's Call Directory Extension, but as far as I know that only enables me to associate a name with the contact for the user, but I don't see a way to programmatically get that associated name to get more information from the API. I suppose I could cram some information from the API into the associated contact's name beforehand, but that is far from ideal.

So is that it?

Comment: No you cannot get any call details and this will never change. This is a fundamental privacy issue. The only way you could achieve the result you are after is to implement a VoIP app and have the user forward their calls to your VoIP service. This way you can get the calling number.